# The transaction currently built is missing an attachment for class - Attempted to find a suitable attachment but could not find any in the storage

Tags: corda

**Full Error:**

```
transactions.TransactionBuilder. - The transaction currently built is missing an attachment for class: com/gibtn/corda/printutilities/PrintLedgerTransaction.  Attempted to find a suitable attachment but could not find any in the storage.
```

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081333/errortransactionbuilder-the-transaction-currently-built-is-missing-an-attac) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778752/adding-custom-metadata-in-bnms-causes-counter-flow-error) but I hope to get better clarification.

**Problem:**

I have built a set of libraries to perform common tasks in my `Flows` that I include in all my CorDapps.  For now I just copy the JARs into each project, make some changes to the gradle files and everything works great.

I recently put together a small library for performing common tasks in `Contracts` and added the JAR the same way.

This works fine with MockNodes.  But when I test with real nodes I will get this error in the CRaSH shell and the transaction will fail with a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

**Question:**

Is what I am doing even possible?  Or do I always have to keep my utility classes inside the `Contracts` module in IntelliJ so they are bundled together with the `Contracts` into a single JAR?  That way when the node starts the JAR (containing the `Contracts` and any utilities) is added to Attachment storage as a single `Attachment`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this.  It's a bit dirty but initial testing seems to work.  I just created a blank class in my utilities JAR that implements `Contract`.  It's `verify()` method is empty.  Now when the Corda node starts it sees this `Contract` and adds the JAR to `Attachment` storage.  So from the CRaSH shell if I run:

```
attachments trustInfo
```

...my utility JAR will be listed (it wasn't before).  I see when I use one of the utility methods in a `Contract` the utility JAR will be included as a separate `Attachment` in the `WireTransaction`.

I'm not crazy about this solution and will probably stop using a utility JAR for `Contracts`.  I'll go back to copying the classes into each project.  Nevertheless there is a way to do it.  I would just need a more experienced Corda developer to give it their blessing before I'd go forward into production with it.

Comment: Hi @Tywin, can you let me know whether you get any recommended solution for this issue, please?

Comment: @Benjamin sorry for delay.  Never heard anything from R3 on this.  Corda 5 is changing lots of things but haven't worked with it enough to test this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Tywin. So the issue happened because your contract utility jar doesnt had any contracts inheriting Contract, correct?

Comment: @Benjamin you are Correct. My utilities were for performing repetitive tasks I found myself doing in many of my contracts. Instead of manually copying in the same code over and over into every contract I just wanted to include a jar. It keeps the contract clean and easier to read. The Contracts I was experimenting with were getting complex and hard to troubleshoot. For example I have a class that will write all the information about the LedgerTransaction into the logs to help me better visualize what has gone wrong if an exception is thrown.